# Collatz Conjecture: Does it follow that there are either an infinite number of nontrivial cycles or none at all

Tags: solution-verification, collatz-conjecture

I was thinking about odd integers when viewing the [collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) in reverse.

In another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4034498/48606), I presented an argument to show that if $x$ is an odd integer, then it resolves in $n$ steps if and only if $4x+1$ resolves in $n$ steps.

It seems to me that if this is true, then there is an argument to be made that there cannot be a finite number of nontrivial cycles

**Let:**

- $\nu_2(x)$ be the [2-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $x$
- $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be $n$ distinct odd integers such that:

  - $x_{i+1} = \dfrac{3x_i + 1}{2^{\nu_2(3x_i+1)}}$
- $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be a nontrivial cycle if all $x_i > 1$ and $x_1 = \dfrac{3x_n+1}{2^{\nu_2(3x_n+1)}}$
- $x_1$ *resolves* in $n$ steps if $\dfrac{3x_n+1}{2^{\nu_2(3x_n + 1)}} = 1$

Here's the argument:

(1) Assume that there are a finite number of nontrivial cycles.

(2) So, let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be all the odd integers that are part of any of these nontrivial cycles.  So, it may not be assumed that any 2 are part of the same cycle.

(3) Let $a$ be the number of $x_i$ where $x_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $b$ the number of $x_j$ where $x_j \equiv 3 \pmod 4$

(4) It follows from step (2) that $n = a + b$

(5) Each $4x_k + 1$ must necessarily be part of a nontrivial cycle (otherwise, $x_k$ cannot be in a nontrivial cycle, by the assumption in the previous question)

(6) Then $b=0$ since each odd integer has a 1-to-1 mapping with a unique $4x_j+1$ which means that $n = a$.

(7) But now we have a contradiction because a nontrivial cycle requires at least $1$ odd integer where $x_k \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

This follows since every odd integer congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ is followed by a smaller odd integer and every odd integer congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ is followed by a larger odd integer.  A nontrivial cycle requires both.

Is my reasoning sound?  Did I make a mistake?

---

**Edit**:  Step (5) is incorrect.  $4x+1$ will end up at $x$ but without being part of a cycle.

Comment: '(5): Each $4x_k+1$ must necessarily be part of a nontrivial cycle' seems wrong to me. $4x_k+1$ must _lead_ to a nontrivial cycle, but that doesn't imply that it's _part_ of a cycle; it could be on the 'tail of the rho' as it were, part of the chain leading into the ultimate cycle.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki In fact, not only *could* that happen, it *must* happen. By definition of cycle, we have $$x_k=c_1\mapsto c_2\mapsto\ldots\mapsto c_r\mapsto c_1,$$ where all $c_i$ are distinct. But also $$4x_k+1\mapsto c_2\mapsto\ldots\mapsto c_r\mapsto c_1\mapsto c_2\mapsto\ldots.$$ So $4x_k+1$ leads to a cycle but is not in a cycle. For example, the trivial cycle is $1\mapsto1\mapsto1\mapsto\ldots$. We also have $5\mapsto1$, $21\mapsto1$, $85\mapsto1$, etc., but none of $5,\ 21,\ 85,\ \ldots$ are in a cycle.

Comment: @WillOrrick I am not clear.  If $x$ is part of a nontrivial cycle, then it does not resolve in any steps.  If $4x+1$ is not part of any nontrivial cycle and it does not resolve in any steps, then does it follow that it must be part of a never-ending sequence? Is that the point? That's a great point.  I hadn't considered never-ending sequences.  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I am not clear what you mean by 'tail of the rho' or 'the ultimate cycle'.  Could you add more details?

Comment: Not quite. Whether $x$ resolves or not is not so important: if $x$ reaches $1$ in $n$ steps then $4x+1$ reaches $1$ in $n$ steps; if $x$ reaches $c_r$ (an element of a nontrivial cycle) in $n$ steps then $4x+1$ reaches $c_r$ in $n$ steps; if $x$ reaches $z$ (an element of a never-ending sequence) in $n$ steps than $4x+1$ reaches $z$ in $n$ steps. The point is that you assumed $x_k$ to be part of a nontrivial cycle. If $x_k$ comes back to $x_k$ after $r$ steps then $4x_k+1$ reaches $x_k$ after $r$ steps. Importantly, $4x_k+1$ never comes back to itself; it is not in a cycle.

Comment: @WillOrrick Thanks!  Got it.  These are great points!  I suspected that there was a mistake in the reasoning.